# Failed To Copy Assets Error

Tags: android, assets

I have images files on assets folder assets/pictures/file.png and i tried to copy those files to SD card.But i get error Failed to copy asset file: " + "pictures/" + name

This is the code that i used to read and copy assets file to SD card

```
String[] getImagesFromAssets() {
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    String[] img_files = null;
    try {
       // img_files = getAssets().list("pictures");
        img_files = assetManager.list("pictures");

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GameActivity.class
                .getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return img_files;


}

void loadImage(String name) {
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

   InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
      in = assetManager.open("pictures/" + name);
      File outFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null)+"/"+"pictures/"+ name);

      out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
      copyFile(in, out);
      in.close();
      in = null;
      out.flush();
      out.close();
      out = null;



      Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(outFile.getAbsolutePath());

      image.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);



    } catch(IOException e) {
        Log.e("tag", "Failed to copy asset file: " + "pictures/" + name, e);
        return;
    } 

}



private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException
{
      byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
      int read;
      while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
      {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
      }
}
```

Update:Logcat

```
01-29 19:39:49.959: I/System.out(12042): winzip.png
01-29 19:39:49.964: I/System.out(12042): vimeo.png
01-29 19:39:49.964: I/System.out(12042): yahoo.png
01-29 19:39:49.964: I/System.out(12042): visa.png
01-29 19:39:49.964: I/System.out(12042): winrar.png
01-29 19:39:49.964: I/System.out(12042): ati.png
01-29 19:39:49.964: I/System.out(12042): benq.png
01-29 19:39:49.964: I/System.out(12042): audi.png
01-29 19:39:49.964: I/System.out(12042): acer.png
01-29 19:39:49.964: I/System.out(12042): wikipedia.png
01-29 19:39:49.964: I/System.out(12042): amd.png
01-29 19:39:49.964: I/System.out(12042): wikimedia.png
01-29 19:39:49.964: I/System.out(12042): aol.png
01-29 19:39:49.964: I/System.out(12042): yamaha.png
01-29 19:39:49.964: I/System.out(12042): vaio.png
01-29 19:39:49.964: I/System.out(12042): wordpress.png
01-29 19:39:49.964: W/Ads(12042): loadAd called while the ad is already loading, so    aborting.
01-29 19:39:49.964: E/tag(12042): Failed to copy asset file: pictures/winzip.png
01-29 19:39:49.964: E/tag(12042): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.appsnthemes.spotthebrand/files/pictures/winzip.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
01-29 19:39:49.964: E/tag(12042):   at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
01-29 19:39:49.964: E/tag(12042):   at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
01-29 19:39:49.964: E/tag(12042):   at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:73)
01-29 19:39:49.964: E/tag(12042):   at com.appsnthemes.spotthebrand.GameActivity.loadImage(GameActivity.java:589)
01-29 19:39:49.964: E/tag(12042):   at com.appsnthemes.spotthebrand.GameActivity.onCreate(GameActivity.java:191)
01-29 19:39:49.964: E/tag(12042):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5369)
01-29 19:39:49.964: E/tag(12042):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
01-29 19:39:49.964: E/tag(12042):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
01-29 19:39:49.964: E/tag(12042):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
01-29 19:39:49.964: E/tag(12042):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:165)
01-29 19:39:49.964: E/tag(12042):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1326)
01-29 19:39:49.964: E/tag(12042):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-29 19:39:49.964: E/tag(12042):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-29 19:39:49.964: E/tag(12042):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5450)
01-29 19:39:49.964: E/tag(12042):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-29 19:39:49.964: E/tag(12042):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-29 19:39:49.964: E/tag(12042):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
01-29 19:39:49.964: E/tag(12042):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
01-29 19:39:49.964: E/tag(12042):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-29 19:39:49.964: E/tag(12042): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
01-29 19:39:49.964: E/tag(12042):   at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
01-29 19:39:49.964: E/tag(12042):   at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
01-29 19:39:49.964: E/tag(12042):   at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)
01-29 19:39:49.964: E/tag(12042):   ... 18 more
```

Comment: You're catching an IO exception and printing out that error message - what's the IO exception?

Comment: @Pedantic  i get this error Failed to copy asset file: pictures/file.png

Comment: I know, that's _your own_ error message which is masking the real error - what's the real error being handled here `Log.e("tag", "Failed to copy asset file: " + "pictures/" + name, e);`, in other words, what's `e`?

Comment: @Pedantic posted logcat

Comment: @Pedantic ? .........

Comment: I'm guessing its because you don't have a 'pictures' subdirectory in your external storage location, you might have to do a `mkdir` call before calling your `copyFile` procedure.

Comment: @Pedantic so how to mkdir?i am not good in programming :)

Comment: @Pedantic ? how to make directory?

Comment: @Pedantic waiting fro your reply

Comment: @Pedantic i successfully made new directory.but problem is images adds to new directory while loading each images to app.it doesn't  copy entire files within folder.so how to achieve this?